# How to have two actions in one form

Tags: php, forms, action

I'm taking up basic web programming and our professor gave this as an exercise in file handling. 1 text file 1 "account" and username as filename. This is a self action form to check "account validity", what I don't know is how to formally submit the verified username to another action file for another file read (Account info etc)

```
<form action="webapp.php" method="POST" id="form1">
<input type = "text" placeholder="Username" name="username" id="username"/>
<input type = "password" placeholder="Password" name="password" id="password" />
<input type="submit" value="Sign in">
<?php
//Login test
if(!empty($_POST)){
$login = $_POST['username1'].".txt";
if(file_exists($login)){
    $fp = fopen($login, 'r');
    $data = fread($fp, filesize($login));
    $pass = explode('!', $data);
    if($_POST['password1'] != $pass[1]){
        echo "<script>alert('Password incorrect');</script>";
        fclose($fp);
    }
    else{//submit username to another action here
```

So basically what I'm asking is how to have two actions in one form using only php and javascript.

Comment: you can use php sessions (http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php) to accomplish this. inside your else statement you start a session and assign the variables you want to transfer to variables in the session. then you can call start the session on a new page, check if the variables you assigned exist (i.e the user is logged in) and hen use the variables on the new page...

Answer (score 0):

When you verify the user, in your else, you can add that users info into sessions. for example:

```
<form action="webapp.php" method="POST" id="form1">
<input type = "text" placeholder="Username" name="username" id="username"/>
<input type = "password" placeholder="Password" name="password" id="password" />
<input type="submit" value="Sign in">
<?php
//Login test
if(!empty($_POST)){
$login = $_POST['username1'].".txt";
if(file_exists($login)){
$fp = fopen($login, 'r');
$data = fread($fp, filesize($login));
$pass = explode('!', $data);

session_start();
if($_POST['password1'] != $pass[1]){
    echo "<script>alert('Password incorrect');</script>";
    fclose($fp);
} else {
    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $_POST['username1'];
    //...more code
}
```

So now when you are on another page/file you can use $_SESSION['user_id'] to hold 'user_id' or any other variable (email, etc). Notice the session_start(); above the if statement; you'll need it on every page you want to use sessions.